# Unexpected token: operator (=) on ES6 class when using Uglifier

Tags: ruby-on-rails, uglifyjs, sprockets, uglifier

I have a JavaScript class in my Rails application that uses Uglifier inside Sprockets to compress the JS (under the hood I believe it uses: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS)

```
class FormValidation {
    connect() {
        this.element.setAttribute('novalidate', true)
        this.element.addEventListener('blur', this.onBlur, true)
    }
    onBlur = (event) => {
        this.validateField(event.target)
    }
... rest of code hidden for benefit of question.
```

And UglifyJS is disliking the `=` in my `onBlur` named method... with `Parse error: Unexpected token: operator (=).`

Harmony is set to true to support ES6... but still getting this error... How can I get around this? As I have had to remove the compression so I can use my class in my code...

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your tooling (babel, packing, etc.), it's hard to say how to get it to build right. but you can always just do the following:

```
class FormValidation {
  connect() {
    this.element.setAttribute('novalidate', true)
    this.element.addEventListener('blur', this.onBlur, true)
  }
}
FormValidation.prototype.onBlur = function(event) {
 this.validateField(event.target)
}
```

Comment: That breaks the code as `this` is no longer the class and becomes the element that triggered the event meaning that the `validateField` method would raise a no method error.

Comment: Also there is no tooling other than Sprockets and Uglifier (using Harmony set to true). Babel is only needed to convert ES6 to ES5... which isn't the aim here... it's to allow uglifier to compress ES6 classes...

Comment: ohh that wasn't evident from the original post. You are using the synctactic sugar to encapsulate ```this```. You should isntead add it as a method to the prototype

Comment: Fancy adding an example of what you mean? Thanks.